# How to implement Server push / long polling / comet using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, server-push

How can I implement the comet / server push design pattern using PHP and Javascript? 
Essentially what I would like is something like this:

- User clicks a 'submit' button
- Javascript shows a message like 'Processing 0 / 100 items'
- Whenever a new item is processed, the php / server pushes out an update, and the javascript changes the message to 'Processing 2/100 items, 3/100 items, and so on'.

How can I do this? Any links/info please?

Answer (score 2):

Comet with PHP has some tricky issues with scaling. An alternative would be a SaaS solution, such as [WebSync On-Demand](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync). (Disclaimer: I work there). That way you don't have to worry about any of the behind the scenes stuff, and you can just get your server-push functionality.

Comment: Not with the On-Demand version - it's SaaS, so it'll work with whatever you're using. For example, I do some of my tests on my personal page, which is running Apache (http://jerodandangela.com/fm-xd.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of very good examples at: [How to implement comet with PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the services use the Client-initiated requests, but there's also [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).  There's a [few](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg28/) [articles](http://ajaxian.com/archives/comet-a-new-approach-to-ajax-applications) out there on it.