# Django refresh page if change data by other user

Tags: django, django-signals, page-refresh

I have a test django app.

In one page the test show the same question to all users.

I'd like that when a user answers correctly, send a signal to other active user's browser to refresh to the next question.

I have been learning about signals in django I learning work with them but I don't now how send the "refresh signal" to client browser.

I think that it can do with a javascript code that check if a certain value (actual question) change and if change reload the page but I don't know this language and the information that I find was confused.

Can anybody help me?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479741/django-push-http-response-to-users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no existing way to send a event from server to browser. But you can get your web page polling your server periodically (say every 5 seconds).

The code in javascript/jquery could be like the following

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.post("your_ajax_handler_url/is_answerd", userId, function(xhr){
       if(xhr.responseText == "answered"){
          location.reload(true);
       }  
    }
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I have a problem, I send the post with the info each 5 seconds but I don't get django view processed the post
The breakpoint in pydev don't pass over it

Comment: Auto response: you need add the decorator csrf_exempt

Answer (score 3):

That is not at all what signals in Django are for. Signals in django are server side hooks that allow you perform tasks on the server when a certain even happens.

To 'send a refresh' to the browser, you need to use a server-push approach such as [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). Alternatively you can get your clients to periodically poll the server to look for update.

Here's some links:

[How to implement Server push / long polling / comet using PHP and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829257/how-to-implement-server-push-long-polling-comet-using-php-and-javascript)

[How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've been read about comet but I think that it's too powerful to my proyect. I'll use the javascript optión to check updates. Many Thanks

Answer (score -1):

What you need are coment(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) and tornado(http://www.tornadoweb.org/)