# Flask with Livereload and Tornado causing error when I run my program

Tags: python, flask, tornado, livereload

Hi this is my first stack post. It's also my first time using Flask. After coding a bit, I found it tedious to refresh my browser each time I made some change in my app.py file or something in template and static.

So I did some research on here to find a way to make the refreshing automatic and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344756/auto-reloading-python-flask-app-upon-code-changes) from which I learned I need to be in debugging mode, and also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379705/flask-auto-reload-does-not-refresh-browser) which showed how to use the livereload library to auto-refresh my browser.

However, I am encountering the following error when I open the link to the server while using livereload:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\learn_flask\env\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1767, in _execute
    result = self.prepare()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\learn_flask\env\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 3149, in prepare
    self.fallback(self.request)
  File "...\learn_flask\env\Lib\site-packages\livereload\server.py", line 133, in __call__
    WSGIContainer.environ(request), start_response)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WSGIContainer.environ() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Here is my entire `app.py` file:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from livereload import Server

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server(app.wsgi_app)
    server.serve()
```

I run the program by typing `python app.py` in PowerShell inside VS code.

I'm not sure but I'm suspicious if the versions of the libraries I have using are incompatible with each other. I'm currently using Python 3.12.1, Flask 3.0.2, Livereload 2.6.3, and Tornado 6.4. I also tried using a few different older versions for all those but I began running into different errors.